# Spring hijacking things (Axis2) want to keep it in separate Runtime or something

Tags: spring, apache-axis

I'm required to load a service in a complicated Spring-defined setup into my application in order to stream data from it.

Unfortunately somehow Spring is having a knock-on effect on existing components in the application - even if no data is definied in the springmodule.xml (somewhat worryingly)

I suspect the components being affected are Axis2 (or JibX). They aren't giving any error per se, just when it comes to reading the port I'm trying to write a message to - that works fine when no spring is involved - and get a message back, they just hang and then time-out.

So if possible I would like to start up a spring-context, let it create the components I want, extract them from the Spring context, and then close down the spring-context so it stops having this knock-on effect on other components. That all works except for getting rid of Spring once I've used it.

I've tried casting the ApplicationContext to ClassApplicationContext (or whatever its called) and invoking .stop() and .close()

but it doesn't fix the problem.

I'd happily start the SpringContext in a separate JVM or runtime if I had an idea how to do this, or if it's plausible, I just need to stop it from interacting with the existing application (Which I suspect detects if Spring is loaded and looks for things from it if it is, and subsequently breaks something)

It must be a similar problem to if you ever wanted to load 2 completely separate spring-contexts in the same program, and came them separate.

Sorry I know this is rambling

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the actual problem was System.getProperties().put( ... ) being called by the guy who wrote the Spring-stuff, and not Spring itself at all.

One of these System-property 'hooks' that he wanted for his component was hooking into Axis2 in other parts of the application and sending it to a different proxy-port, overriding the one it was supposed to go to, and then hanging on the port when no connection was made.

Comment: * so the solution is obviously just to remove the properties he added once the components have been instantiated.